# cordova Javascript require('fs') is stopping my code

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile, filesystems

I've been working on a mobile app in Visual Studio 2017, I need to do some file access but have struggled for the last week.
what i have is:

```
function findCampaignFolders() {
    alert("in find folder");
    var fs = require('fs');
    alert("finally past file system");
    var Folders = fs.readdirSync("/Campagins");
    var textString = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < Folders.length; i++)
    {
        textString = textString + Folders[i];
    }
    alert(textString);
}
```

when this function is called `alert("in find folder");`works and sends it promt.

but  `alert("finally past file system");` never fires or anything after.

the cordova is predicted with `fs.readdirSync ()` so it recognized in the VS2017.

as for scripts load order in looks like in HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/Objects.js"></script>
```

Objects.js is where my function lives.

If anyone can at least give me a hint as why i can't get this working or if there is another way i can go about it it would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var fs = require('fs');` is Node.js code that doesn't work on Cordova apps. Node.js code is meant to be used on a server or on CLI apps, but not in client apps such as Cordova.

To read/write files in Cordova you have to use `cordova-plugin-file` https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

Comment: According to VS 2017 config.xml tells me i have it installed, yet it dose not recognize window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL().
cordova.file.applicationDirectory

Comment: That's a different issue, but you can't use the `require('fs');` in a Cordova app. If you are not able to use `cordova-plugin-file` in your app create a new question and provide the new code there